# How can I speed up this block of code?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a lot of duplicate records that I'm trying to weed out, and to do that, I'm currently running this:

```
Survey.active.each do |survey|
  survey.response_sets.completed.each do |set|
    answer_ids = []
    set.responses.each do |r|
      if r.answer.blank?
        r.destroy
      else
        if answer_ids.include? r.answer_id
          r.destroy
        else
          answer_ids << r.answer_id
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That finds all active surveys, gets the response sets for each survey, then the individual responses for each response set.

It then looks to see if a response is a duplicate based on if `answer_id` exists for another response within the response set. Within a given response set, there can only be one response for a given `answer_id`. So, if there are duplicates, it destroys the duplicate.

Over a couple hundred thousand rows, that is going *very* slow.

So, how can I speed that process up?

Here are the SQL calls for each of those:

```
Survey.active
SELECT "surveys".* FROM "surveys" WHERE "surveys"."active" = 't'

survey.response_sets.completed
SELECT "response_sets".* FROM "response_sets" WHERE ("response_sets".survey_id = 12345) AND (completed_at IS NOT NULL)

set.responses
SELECT "responses".* FROM "responses" WHERE ("responses".response_set_id = 54321)
```

I'm running Rails 3.0.6 and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Just a general SQL tip, ask yourself do you really need to do `SELECT *` on all your queries? Unfortunately, I do not know any Ruby or RoR to help you further :(

Comment: you could try using a hash to track the answer_ids you have already seen rather than an array. You might also want to try adding some includes and using find_each rather than each on the outermost loop (otherwise you'll be keeping al the objects you previously looked at resident in ram). Obviously, ensure that you have indexes on all the appropriate columns. Changing `r.answer.blank?` to `r.answer_id.blank` will save a lot of queries (but if you don't have foreign keys means that you won't catch 'dangling' answer_ids

Comment: Try wrapping the whole smash in a transaction (`Survey.transaction do`...`end`).  That can allow Postgresql to go faster.  Also, see if you can just use psql to drive postgres directly to to the cleanup, bypassing rails/activerecord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be attacking this from the wrong angle. You should never allow the bad data into the database in the first place. I cannot really see how your database model looks like but some validations in the models might prevent you from having to clean the database like this. Loading really big datasets in Rails is a pain, and it's really slow and memory hungry.

```
# maybe something like this?
class Responses < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :answer_id, :scope => :id
end
```

*Batch tip (added)*

Activerecord doesn't really work well with large result sets. If you have will_paginate or something similar you can easily loop through the full dataset in pieces.

```
(1..Survey.total_pages).each do |p|
   Survey.paginate(:page => p, :per_page => 30).each do |survey|
     # your loop but with less memory overhead
```

Comment: I've already fixed the issue that was causing duplicates, so I'm definitely attacking from the right angle here. :)

Comment: OK, missed that you were looking for a once over fix, added a quick little solution for minimizing the memory overhead which is probably what is slowing down the run.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run that only once, what's the problem? If it's a "daily" task you can use a background job to handle that (take a look at the delayed job or resque gems).

But there are several things you could do. Are you `including` the answers in the scope? or use `Survey.active.includes(:answers)`

There's also a method called `find_each` for AR models that *should* be faster when working with large datasets.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, here: are you sure that the fields you're using in the WHERE clauses are indexed?

That's purely an SQL issue rather than a Rails one (just as well, I am a Rails n00b :) ), but...

```
response_sets.survey_id, 
response_sets.completed_at 
responses.response_set_id
```

should definitely all have indexes set on them if you're talking about datasets of several hundred rows.

Comment: Yeah, I feel pretty sure I've got the indexes covered.

Comment: The only other thing I can think might be worth doing is some timing metrics on those queries, just to see where the biggest time penalty lies.

It wouldn't hurt to hand-execute some of the queries in a Postgres client, to see what kind of performance you're getting from the database...that would at least tell you whether the big hits are being taken in the Rails code or the SQL, and might give SO types a bit more to go on...!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a problem best solved using SQL instead of iterating each record in ruby.

SQL is still a powerful tool when you need to do this type of operation

```
#Delete responses that do not have a corresponding answer
#AND delete responses that have a duplicate answer_id keeping only one response for each answer_id
ActiveRecord::Base.execute <<-SQL
  DELETE FROM responses
  WHERE (responses.answer_id IS NULL) OR
  (
    responses.id NOT IN (
      -- build a list of the response ids you want to keep
      SELECT responses.id
      FROM responses
      INNER LEFT JOIN 
      (
        -- get a list of responses with a unique answer id
        SELECT DISTINCT responses.answer_id
        FROM responses
      )
      -- join responses to itself on the unique list of answer ids
      -- keeping only a single record for each answer id
      as answer_ids ON responses.answer_id = answer_ids.answer_id
    )
  )
SQL
```

**NOTE**: I haven't tested this and I recommend running it against a test environment first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe group your results by answer_id and select only those which have COUNT(*) > 1?

It could go something like this:

```
survey.response_sets.completed.all(
  :group_by => "answer_id",
  :select => "id, answer_id, COUNT(*) AS count_duplicates",
  :conditions => "count_duplicates > 1")
```

Then go through all these answer_ids and destroy all but the first one:

```
duplicate_sets.group_by(:answer_id) {|...|
```

This will give you an array of all ids grouped by each answer id. Just strip the first element, destroy the rest.

I'm not sure about your models, so I leave the rest to you. But it should give you the clue how to prepare your data before actually working on it. My code also does not select the `answer_id IS NULL` case but these should be easy to spot in a second run.

Be sure to wrap everything into a transaction so your data is not changed during preparation and duplicate elimination.